# 14.04 server, upstart, network interfaces, and frustrated

Tags: networking, server

Looking for a bit of assistance here.

I upgraded from 10.04 to 14.04 last night and now I can't get my network to start-up properly.

It is a multi-homed system and I use iptables2 to route traffic accordingly. My configuration is the same as it has been for ages, but the new Ubuntu won't bring up the interfaces properly.

The first interface, eth0 does come up during boot but none of the 'up' scripts are run. I did try 'post-up' also without any success.  The 14.04 man page for interfaces says these are still supported...

Either way, I get stuck in the dreaded "Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration" hang at boot and no routing.

If I manually try ifup with the interfaces set to 'auto ethX' then I get an error.  If I comment out the auto lines, then I can get the ifup to work properly (including the up scripts).

So I did try to add '/sbin/ifup eth0 ; sleep 2 ; /sbin/ifup eth1' to the failsafe.conf file, but that too doesn't quite work.  eth0 comes up properly, but eth1 does not.

I am thoroughly confused as to what is going on with this...  I thought about adding a startup script don't even know where to begin with this upstart thing in terms of ordering...  I just need the interfaces to be up before my main service daemon tries to start -- else it will fail startup because the interface is not there to bind to.

Thanks.  -Cheers, Peter.

```
/etc/network/interfaces
-----
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Management Net interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.50.52
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 up /sbin/ip route add 192.168.50.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.50.52 table mgmtroute
 up /sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.50.254 table mgmtroute
 up /sbin/ip rule add from 192.168.50.0/24 table mgmtroute

# Public Net interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
 address 192.168.60.52
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.60.254
 up /sbin/ip route add 192.168.60.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.60.52 table hostingroute
 up /sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.60.254 table hostingroute
 up /sbin/ip rule add from 192.168.60.0/24 table hostingroute
```

**UPDATE:**
Hi Katu,

I tried what you mentioned, but it doesn't work.  The startup script ends up running before the interfaces are up (after loopback is up and the fallback script completes) if the auto ethX is commented out.

It also doesn't work if the auto ethX lines are not commented out because the interface comes up without the route (up commands not run) and the eth1 interface never comes up automatically.

**UPDATE2:**
I haven't been able to solve this... I filed a bug on launchpad for Ubuntu -- Bug #1472055 and will update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to start your service daemon adding a script in the folder

```
/etc/network/if-up.d/
```

It will run after the network interfaces are up.

Until you solve the problem, if you want to avoid waiting for 60 seconds every time the network interfaces fail, you can edit the sleep lines in the file

```
/etc/init/failsafe.conf
```